# Strange CouchDB error, how to understand it?

Tags: docker, couchdb

Can someone help me understand this couchdb error. I'm not sure what is different than before. Does it have something to do with my configuration. Is it possible to test it?

CouchDB 1.6.1

 `{"error":"{{badmatch,[]},\n [{couch_server,get_lru,1,[{file,\"couch_server.erl\"},{line,262}]},\n
{couch_server,try_close_lru,1,[{file,\"couch_server.erl\"},{line,235}]},\n  {couch_server,maybe_close_lru_db,1,[{file,\"couch_server.erl\"},{line,228}]},\n  {couch_server,open_db,4,[{file,\"couch_server.erl\"},{line,490}]},\n  {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,629}]},\n  {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,661}]},\n  {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,240}]}]}","reason":"{gen_server,call,\n    [couch_server,\n     {open,<<\"user/5iooesr\">>,\n
   [{user_ctx,\n              {user_ctx,<<\"_hoodie\">>,\n                  [<<\"_admin\">>],\n                  <<\"{couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}\">>}}]},\n     infinity]}"}`

I don't know how I did this, it seems to like couchdb is in a broken state sometimes. I run it in a docker container on the server. I never had that error during development. But now after some months in production (daily restarts) it seems to popup on some days and then couchdb is not accepting any requests from my app and floods my log files with those kind of errors.

Comment: What did you do to generate this error?

Comment: I don't know the answer. But I suggest updating to CouchDB 2.1.1, since version 1.6.1 has [security bugs](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-19046/Apache-Couchdb.html).